# Excel-VBA: Application.index not working?

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I have a 2D variant having 100 rows and 20 columns. I need to extract part of it and store it in another array.

If I do the following, it works perfectly:

```
HourReport = Application.index(HourReportBodyTable, [row(1:22)], Array(1, 2, 3))
```

The issue I am having is that the row boundaries are not fixed and they can change. So when I do the following, it does not work

```
HourReport = Application.index(HourReportBodyTable, [row(FirstEntryIndex:LastEntryIndex)], Array(1, 2, 3))
```

FirstEntryIndex and LastEntryIndex are both integers set to 1 and 22 respectively. Does anyone know why the second code is not working?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Evaluate method to return an array of row numbers...

```
With Application
    HourReport = .Index(HourReportBodyTable, .Evaluate("row(" & FirstEntryIndex & ":" & LastEntryIndex & ")"), Array(1, 2, 3))
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

## Slice Array

- The following only applies to 2D one-based arrays, e.g. retrieved from a range.
- The `Index` function is rather slow. A short code isn't necessarily efficient.
- Here's how you could write your own function.
- I've added the possibility to revert the rows and/or columns i.e. if the first row or column index is greater than the last, the result will be in reverse order (see the 2nd example (screenshot)).

### The Calls (Usage)

**In Your Particular Case**

```vb
HourReport = GetSlicedData(HourReportBodyTable, 1, 22, 1, 3)
HourReport = GetSlicedData(HourReportBodyTable, FirstEntryIndex, LastEntryIndex, 1, 3)
```

**Normal**

[image]

```vb
Sub GetSlicedDataTEST1()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim sData() As Variant: sData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
        Dim dData() As Variant: dData = GetSlicedData(sData, 4, 7, 2, 4)
        .Range("G2").Resize(UBound(dData, 1), UBound(dData, 2)).Value = dData
    End With
End Sub
```

**Reverted Rows and Columns**

[image]

```
Sub GetSlicedDataTEST2()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim sData() As Variant: sData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
        Dim dData() As Variant: dData = GetSlicedData(sData, 7, 4, 4, 2)
        .Range("G2").Resize(UBound(dData, 1), UBound(dData, 2)).Value = dData
    End With
End Sub
```

### The Function

```vb
Function GetSlicedData( _
    SourceData() As Variant, _
    ByVal FirstRow As Long, _
    ByVal LastRow As Long, _
    ByVal FirstColumn As Long, _
    ByVal LastColumn As Long) _
As Variant
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(SourceData, 1)
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = UBound(SourceData, 2)
 
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = LastRow - FirstRow
    Dim rStep As Long: rStep = -(2 * (drCount > 1) + 1)
    drCount = rStep * (drCount + rStep)
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = LastColumn - FirstColumn
    Dim cStep As Long: cStep = -(2 * (dcCount > 1) + 1)
    dcCount = cStep * (dcCount + cStep)

    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)

    Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, dr As Long, dc As Long
    
    For sr = FirstRow To LastRow Step rStep
        dr = dr + 1
        dc = 0
        For sc = FirstColumn To LastColumn Step cStep
            dc = dc + 1
            dData(dr, dc) = SourceData(sr, sc)
        Next sc
    Next sr
    
    GetSlicedData = dData

End Function
```